# How to adjust sharpness ,brightness and Contrast of an image in android?

Tags: android, image, graphics

I need to adjust sharpness, brightness and Contrast of an image . I am not getting proper output. I follow these tutorials for
  [Sharpness](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-sharpening-image/),[brightness](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/),[contrast](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-contrast-image-on-the-fly/). But I am not getting proper output in case of sharpness. There are any library can adjust image sharpness, brightness and Contrast in android.

Comment: After long time, i can find out my requirement and i can use as per my requirement .I found a good library which is work good.https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage. It is may be helpfull for others

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JJIL](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jjil/) library.

Also you can check this [example](http://www.richardnichols.net/2011/01/java-facial-recognition-haar-cascade-with-jjil-guide/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can i i adjust sharpness ,brightness, and Contrast using this

Answer (score -2):

Add the following library in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
```

And now use the following code to increase your image quality in your ImageView.

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(image_url)
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: Hi @Apporv, i want to to edit image with sharpness, brightness and Contrast not download